# Get children category of a taxonomy by parent id

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom post type "project" with a taxonomy "taxoproject"and I have a template page "template-project.php" with a query loop to display my post.

In this loop I need to display each category associated with the post.

This is my code :

```
<ul>
   <?php
     $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxoproject');
     foreach($terms as $term) { ?>

         <li>
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
         </li>

     <?php }
   ?>
</ul>
```

My code works perfectly with one exception, I wish to display only the children of a specific parent of this taxonomy (id 76) and I do not know how to proceed.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem :

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $taxonomy = 'taxoproject'; // Taxonomy slug.
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

        $children = '';

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if( $term -> parent == 76 ) { // Parent ID 
                $children = $term->name; ?>

                <li><?php echo $children; ?></li>

            <?php } 
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Thank you all for the help !

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php
  // use taxonomy slug
   $terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'taxoproject',
    'hide_empty' => true,
  ]);
 foreach($terms as $term) { ?>

     <li>
        <?php echo $term->post_title;?>

       </li>

      <?php }
```

?>

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work at all for me, where does I put my parent Id for show the specific children i want ?

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand your code. With my code i get all the children of my taxonomy's parents, but why I want is the children of a specific parent (I think with an ID parameter it would work but I dont know how)

Comment: $taxonomies = array('taxoproject','post_tags','my-tax');
 
 $args = array(
     'hide_empty' => 0
 );

 $terms = get_terms( $taxonomies, $args);

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will work for you

```
<ul>
   <?php
     $parent = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'taxoproject', 'hide_empty' => 1, 'parent' => 76 ) );
     foreach($parent as $term) { ?>

         <li>
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
         </li>

     <?php }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I have an error : "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" do you know where it can come from?

Comment: I have updated my code, please try after replacing it.

Comment: Please print your variable parent before foreach using this syntax : print_r($parent);
let me know what's the result

Comment: My bad your code works, but it return all the child from the parent not the one select in the different post.

Answer (score 0):

$makes = get_terms('pa_modal', array('hide_empty' => false ));

$children = '';

```
    foreach ( $makes as $term ) {
        if( $term -> parent == 959 ) { // Parent ID 
            $children = $term->name; ?>

            <li><?php echo $children; ?></li>

        <?php } 
    }
```

print_r($makes);
exit;

https://www.findinall.com/blogs/get-children-category-of-a-taxonomy-by-parent-id/
Link source